# How to retrieve Ethernet adapter name in Windows 8.1 batch script

Tags: batch-file, networking, windows-8.1, static-ip-address

I'm looking to pull the Ethernet adapter name out of ipconfig to use in a batch script which will create a static ip to that adapter name using netsh.

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : foo.bar.com
    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.123
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.456
```

What I am trying to do is pull out Ethernet0 and use that in the following netsh command (net_city and net_lab are inputted by the user).

```
netsh interface ip set address "<adapter name>" static 10.%net_city%.15%net_lab%.235 255.255.255.0 10.%net_city%.15%net_lab%.1 1
```

What would be the best way to retrieve the name? I have begun looking into regex to try and filter out the name.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you assuming there is only one interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested, you can use `netsh` to gather a list of interfaces, and then get the user to select one using `choice`. Here is my implementation of that:

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set c=0
set "choices="

echo Interfaces -

for /f "skip=2 tokens=3*" %%A in ('netsh interface show interface') do (
    set /a c+=1
    set int!c!=%%B
    set choices=!choices!!c!
    echo [!c!] %%B
)

choice /c !choices! /m "Select Interface: " /n

set interface=!int%errorlevel%!
echo %interface%
```

The choice command changes the value of `errorlevel`, and by making the name of each variable comprising your list of interfaces `int1`, `int2`, etc. you can simply call them with `!int%errorlevel%!` after the choice command.

If you can assume there will only ever be one interface, then you can simply do the following.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3*" %%A in ('netsh interface show interface') do set interface=%%B

echo %interface%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3*" %%A in ('netsh interface show interface') do set interface=%%B

netsh interface ip set address name=%interface% static 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the following, then use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435884/creating-a-batch-file-to-identify-the-active-internet-connection) to select the correct interface.

```
C:\Scripts>netsh interface show interface
Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Local Area Connection
```