# How to release the IP/Lease from CMD/Batch

Tags: batch-file, network-programming, ip, router

I already did a google search and only found Ubuntu stuff.

To the point: I want to create a mini tool in batch that will change my public IP address.

According to this guide:
http://www.howtogeek.com/103190/change-your-ip-address-from-the-command-prompt/

This command should do the trick

```
netsh interface ip4 set address name=”YOUR INTERFACE NAME” source=dhcp
```

One problem. I want to share this w/ others who don't know how to get their interface name from

```
netsh interface ipv4 show config
```

So I'm looking for a way to make this a batch file that I can share and automatically just send to all my friends and have them click and go, nothing more. How do I select the default adapter, or the one that's currently being used.

If you have a better solution I would love to take that aswell.

**I'm attempting to do this in batch***

Thanks!

EDIT: I found a solution here: If anyone else is having the same problem
[How to retrieve Ethernet adapter name in Windows 8.1 batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523583/how-to-retrieve-ethernet-adapter-name-in-windows-8-1-batch-script?rq=1)

and I took the code and used the %interface% variable to do the command like this:

```
netsh interface ip4 set address name=%interface% source=dhcp
```

Comment: In many cases their public IP address will be set to a value within the range allocated to their ISP and probably set at their router. In that case your batch script would be unlikely to achieve your intended goal.

Comment: @Compo is it not possible for the computer to request an IP change

Comment: @Compo would ipconfig /release work?

Comment: @Compo update, a few of my users reported it as working so I'm thinking it works.

Comment: It depends upon their setups, most people will have a network IP Address, certainly over here, something like 192.168.0._n_, where n could be 1 to 3 integers. However their public IP Address will appear in a range as provided by their IP and set externally of their Operating System.

Comment: @Compo I'm just looking to send a request to the router to release the public ip/ dhcp lease so we can get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I found a solution here: If anyone else is having the same problem
[How to retrieve Ethernet adapter name in Windows 8.1 batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523583/how-to-retrieve-ethernet-adapter-name-in-windows-8-1-batch-script?rq=1)

and I took the code and used the %interface% variable to do the command like this:

```
netsh interface ip4 set address name=%interface% source=dhcp
```

EDIT:

You can also use this:

```
ipconfig /release
```

It depends per setup if it works but for me it works fine ;)